# Angular HttpClient with Custom ViewModel

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am leveraging HttpClient instead of Http for my service call along with Observable which works well. However, I want to map some of the custom properties. Is that something we can fetch and map?

To give you background: I have
One service: this calls web api and pack the result in Observable> like>

```
getArticles(): Observable<Array<ArticleViewModel>> {
   return this.httpClient.get<Array<ArticleViewModel>>(this.url.articleurl);
}
```

next I have component, which calls this server like:

```
getArticles(): void {
  this.articles = this.articleService.getArticles();
}
```

finally, I have ViewModel which has all the properties of Article ViewModel.

However, the Web Api returns much more properties than I have in my Angular View Model. Moreover, some of the properties has different name than I have in Angular VM.
So, I want to map those with correct properties and further I want to use some of the web api properties just to validate before setting up Angular Property value.

But the same time, I don't want to use http (`@angular/http`). I want to continue with latest httpclient (`@angular/common/http`). 
But that service directly map the result with my angular view model.

so is that something we can create view model meaningfully by checking all the web api properties?

[image]

Comment: do you later call `this.articles.subscribe(res => {}, err => {}, () => {})` or something similar?

Comment: If your server sends `Foo`, and your view model is `FooSlightlyModified`, then what you need to do is modify `Foo` before passing it to your template. You can do this with RxJS operators like `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's even really easy !

```js
return this
  .httpClient
  .get<ArticleViewModel[]>(this.url.articleurl)
  .map(articles => {
    const mapped: ArticleViewModel[] = [];
    for (let article of articles) {
      const _a = new ArticleViewModel(/* fields */);
      mapped.push(_a);
    }
    return mapped;
  });
```

If you have a constructor in your class, this will be a piece of cake with that !

Comment: sorry, may be I am new to angular and that's why taking time to understand. I have tried to implement your code in my service class inside getarticles() methos. However there are two issues I am getting (1) a function whose declared type neither void nor any must need to return type
(2) you have commented /* fields */ can you please guide how can I use that area to get the new property value from the api url ? note: that is some different property name than my angular view model has.

Comment: 1) remove the `: void` after the parameters of your function 2) this is a constructor like you would see in every other language. Is it your first time programming ? If so, I advise you take a course or look at a tutorial on object oriented programming. This will explain you how constructors work.

Comment: Hi, I have modified that in service class not in component. so, void is in component which probably we don't need to change. Moreover, I have added the debugger screenshot in main question. if you can check and guide me further

Comment: Definitely learn about object oriented programming. I won't teach you that right now on stack overflow.

Comment: make sense. Thanks.

Comment: Hi trichetriche, I don't think your solution will also work. because you code also directly map the items into ArticleViewModel [see the mapping httpClient.get<ArticleViewModel[]>(this.url.articleurl)].
Here the question is what about those properties which we don't have in our Angular View Model - ArticleViewModel How to get those in account ?

Comment: It's working now. I am accepting your answer sir.

constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        console.log(values);
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }

Comment: @Brijesh nice shortcut ! Glad it works for you then, but be careful because this shortcut will keep the values you don't want !